# Observable to reuse operator executions

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, kotlin

Given the following example (kotlin code)

```
val subject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()

val stream = subject.map {
    println("mapping")
    it * 2
}

stream.forEach { println("A: $it") }
stream.forEach { println("B: $it") }

subject.onNext(1)
subject.onCompleted()
```

output will be

```
mapping
A: 2
mapping
B: 2
```

what i want to achieve is that source observable is being mapped once and all the subscribers get the result, but not execute the mapping operation for each and every one of them...

like this

```
mapping
A: 2
B: 2
```

In my case i have very expensive computation going on where latency and performance are critical, i have a hot observable as a source and lots of subscribers...

**How do we reuse operator executions? and generally different mapping operations?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`cache`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#cache()) to cache the result of source observable to any future subscriber:

```
val stream = subject.map {
    println("mapping")
    it * 2
}.cache()
```

If you want a more subtle control over how things are cached the [`replay`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#replay()) is worth looking into.

If you do not want to cache each item of source observable but only *republish* new items you can use [`publish`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#publish()) with [`autoConnect`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/ConnectableObservable.html#autoConnect()):

```
val stream = subject.map {
    println("mapping")
    it * 2
}.publish()
 .autoConnect()
```

Which given the following sequence of events:

```
stream.forEach { println("A: $it") }
stream.forEach { println("B: $it") }

subject.onNext(1)

stream.forEach { println("C: $it") }
subject.onNext(2)
subject.onCompleted()
```

Would print:

```
mapping
A: 2
B: 2
mapping
A: 4
B: 4
C: 4
```

Comment: oh gosh this is really bad, i just checked sources for operators, every single subscriber executes everything in the chain...

cache does not do what i look for, i dont want to store all emittions anywhere, i just want it to calculate and propogate to everyone instead of calculating for everyone :(

Comment: i know this is asking for a favour but could you please copy and modify the OperatorMap (basic mapping operator) so that it invokes transformer only once... I just need to see what is the correct way to do this... if any

Comment: debugging into the workflow, it seems like i have wrong understanding how this works, original source observable has two observers so the devision comes right from the root, where i expected it to have one subscriber and this in its turn has other 2...

Comment: Is there other RX framework that does not work this way? this is designed to be this way... every single subscriber executes entire chain work for himself nothing is reused... very bad design imho, especially considering that RX intends that we use pure functions and immutable data... why do the same work for 100 subscribers if it should be done only once...

Comment: Nice, i'll accept this as answer although i'm sticking with my solution cos it will at least create less objects and does not look like a hack. 

Also your solution is applicable to pure java cos you could use that and not break the chain, while mine only will work if you have awesomeness called "extension functions"... Thanks for answer :)

Comment: I've downvoted by mistake, and now cannot upvote it :( Can you make little changes so I can upvote this? Sorry again.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. In order to reuse the execution of the pipe, we must make sure that there is only one subscriber and this subscriber propagates all emissions from the end of the pipe to the entries of all subscribers... Which sounds a lot like Subject!

If we just subscribe 100 times we will have 100 pipes starting from the very source observable, while in this case we have one pipe, which branches to 100 tiny pipes in the very end of it...

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.hub(): Observable<T> {
    val hub = PublishSubject.create<T>()
    this.subscribe(hub)
    return hub
}
```

now we can do this

```
val subject = PublishSubject.create<Int>()

val stream = subject.map {
    println("mapping")
    it * 2
}

val hub = stream.hub()

hub.subscribe { println("A: $it") }
hub.subscribe { println("B: $it") }

subject.onNext(1)

subject.onCompleted()
```

which will give this

```
mapping
A: 2
B: 2
```

problem solved!